# How to include both import and require statements in the bundle using rollup

Tags: javascript, bundle, es6-modules, commonjs, rollup

When I use only `const Example1 = require('./example1.js)` statement then code inside **example1.js** file is getting included in the bundle. And if I use only `import Example2 from './example2.js'` then also code inside example2.js is getting included in the bundle. But if I use both the statements only `import` is working and `require` is not working.

I am using rollup for bundling.

My rollup configuration looks like this

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import url from 'rollup-plugin-url'
import svg from 'rollup-plugin-svg'
import json from 'rollup-plugin-json';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser'

export default {
  input: 'src/sdk/test.js',
  output: [
    {
      file: "src/sdk/sdk.js",
      format: 'cjs'
    },
    {
      file: "src/sdk/sdk.es.js",
      format: 'es'
    },
    {
      file: "src/sdk/sdk.iife.js",
      format: 'iife'
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      browser: true,
    }),
    commonjs(),
    external(),
    postcss({
      modules: true
    }),
    url({
      limit: 100 * 1024,
      emitFiles: false
    }),
    svg(),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
    }),
    terser(),
    json()
  ]
}
```

Comment: Well, no, just don't mix the two module syntaxes.

Comment: I wish I could @Bergi

Answer (score 3):

By default, rollup supports 'esm' modules as entry. If you like to include commonjs files in the project, you can include '@rollup/plugin-commonjs' into plugins field, it usually works.

Maybe the following config will help, I tried with very simple example:

```
commonjs({transformMixedEsModules:true})
```

**transformMixedEsModules**
Instructs the plugin whether or not to enable mixed module transformations. This is useful in scenarios with mixed ES and CommonJS modules. Set to true if it's known that require calls should be transformed, or false if the code contains env detection and the require should survive a transformation.

https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs

Comment: But it doesn't include the code from ```require``` statement in the final bundle. ```require``` statement with path will remain as it is. Only ```import``` statement code will be included.

Comment: is it  third party modules or codes you wrote doesn't get bundled? You did not explain

Comment: its a third party library tweenjs

Comment: I want to add `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js` to the rollup. How can I do that? I mean, I want to add this Alert message to my widget `https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_alerts_fade&stacked=h`. But JS files are not working.

Comment: @OsandaGamage did you figure it out?