# React -Vite require not defined in build but works fine in dev

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, require, vite

I have built a small practice project using React and Vite, and everything worked well in the development environment.

However, when I built it and attempted to preview it, I encountered the following error:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined."

The issue is that I do not use the 'require' function in my code, I only use imports. Is this related to the npm packages that I have installed?

If so, how can I find the correct package to fix it or are there any other solutions?

I attempted to install a plugin called 'vite-require' but it did not work (maybe I did something incorrectly).

I am writing here in hopes of finding a solution to this issue.

Thank you for any answers in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include both import and require statements in the bundle using rollup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770883/how-to-include-both-import-and-require-statements-in-the-bundle-using-rollup)